# How to insert a delta function upon equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I was asked to find the impulse response of the equation :

```
y[n]−0.5y[n−1]=−0.5x[n]+x[n−1]
```

I used this code:

```
A = [1,-0.5] ; 
B = [-0.5,1] ;
X1 = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ; % Impulse insert 
y1 = filter(B,A,X1);
```

Now I've been asked to calculate the system response for:

```
x[n]=−0.3δ[n+2]+2δ[n]+1.5δ[n−3]−δ[n−5]
```

Can someone suggest a way?

Comment: Why do you not transform it to `X1 = [-0.3  0  2  0 0 1.5  0  -1]` as you have done in your supplied code?

Comment: There's a nice explanation here: http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/impulse-function.html   that you could probably vectorize quite simply.

Comment: i tried it but I'm not certain about the result..